# Pytorch does all training data requires gradient if I do mini-batching?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, neural-network, tensor

Lets say I have a function that creates mini batches using bootstrapping from a set of positive and negative labeled elements:

```
def get_bootstrap_batch(positive_examples, negative_examples, idx, shuffle=True):
    # Truncate the length if we are at the last batch to avoid over indexing
    seq_len = min(BATCH_SIZE, len(positive_examples) - 1 - idx)

    # Grab a batch from the positives with index idx
    positives = positive_examples[idx:idx + seq_len]

    # Get a random staring position from the indexes of the negative set for bootstraping
    slice_pos = int(torch.randint(len(negative_examples)-BOOTSTRAP_SIZE, (1,)))

    # Get a bootstrap sized slice from negatives from slice_pos
    negatives = negative_examples[slice_pos:slice_pos+BOOTSTRAP_SIZE, :, :]

    # Concat the obtained data, these require gradient
    data = torch.concat([positives, negatives])
    target = torch.concat([torch.full((positives.shape[0], ), 1, dtype=torch.float), torch.full((negatives.shape[0], ), 0, dtype=torch.float)])

    # Shuffle the bootstrap
    if shuffle:
        p = torch.randperm(positives.size(0))
        data = data[p, :, :]
        target = target[p]

    return data, target.to(device)
```

And I have a training cycle like this:

```
net = some_model_class(...)
positive_set_train = torch.tensor(..., requires_grad=True)
negative_set_train = torch.tensor(..., requires_grad=True)
for batch, i in enumerate(range(0, positive_set_train.size(0) - 1, BATCH_SIZE)):
    
    net.train()  # turn on train mode

    data, targets = get_bootstrap_batch(positive_set_train, negative_set_train, i)
    optimizer.zero_grad()  # zero the gradient buffers
    output = net(data)
    
    loss = criterion(output, targets)
    train_loss += loss.item() * data.size(0)
    loss.backward()

    optimizer.step()  # Does the update
```

My question is can I turn off `requires_grad` for `positive_set_train` and `negative_set_train` to save memory? Am I understanding it correctly, that in the bootstrap function a new object called `data` will be created which has `requires_grad=True` by default and it is the only thing that is required for the training of the network?

Comment: It looks like in most cases `torch.cat` is copy by value rather than reference, so new memory is allocated. In any case you probably need to call `torch.cat(... requires_grad = True)` to ensure the gradient, I believe by default `torch.cat` copies the `requires_grad` attribute from its inputs. But I'd also say that in most cases gradient is not required for inputs to a model https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/do-i-need-to-have-requires-grad-true-for-input-when-switch-from-pytorch-0-3-to-1-0/39543.

Comment: `requires_grad=True` is only for tensor for which you want to compute the gradients. Typically the values you want to update by gradient descent. In you case you need the gradients of the parameters in `net` but not in `positive_examples`, `negative_examples` or `data`. By default parameters have `requires_grad=True` and the later tensors have `requires_grad=False`. You should keep it like that

Comment: @ValentinGoldité Thanks a lot, perfectly clear, I thought in some way the gradient of a given batch is stored in the batch data tensor instead of the network. In this case however why is the default behavior requires_grad=True if it is only required for the network itself?

Comment: I made a complete answer below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requires_grad=True` is only for tensor for which you want to compute the gradients. Typically the values you want to update by gradient descent. In you case you need the gradients of the parameters in `net` but not in `positive_examples`, `negative_examples` or `data`.

By default all the tensors you create and all the tensors derived from operation on them have `requires_grad=False`. However the parameters of a neural network have `requires_grad=True`.

Example:

```py
x = torch.tensor([0.6])
print(x.requires_grad)  # False
y = torch.tensor([0.4])
xy = torch.cat([x[None, :, y[None, :])
print(xy.requires_grad)  # False

net = torch.nn.Linear(2, 1, bias=False)
weight = net.weight
print(weight.requires_grad)  # True
```

We can go further. A tensor that is not a parameter but derived from an operation involving a tensor with `requires_grad=True` have `requires_grad=True` itself (even if other tensors used in the operation have not).

Example:

```py
z = net(xy.T)
print(z.requires_grad) # True
loss = torch.mean((z - torch.tensor([0.5]))**2)  # MSE
print(loss.requires_grad) # True
```

**Ok but what does `tensor.requires_grad=True` means precisely (for any tensor `tensor`) ?**

It means that after calling `loss.backward()`, if `tensor` is used in computation of `loss`, the gradients `d loss / d tensor` will be computed. Then, if `tensor` is not the result of an operation itself (typically if it is a parameter), these gradients will be store in `tensor.grad`. We call these tensor the "leaves".

Example:

```py
loss.backward()
# Intermediate tensor:
print(z.is_leaf)  # False
print(z.grad)  # UserWarning: `z` is not a leaf
# Leaf that requires grad (parameter):
print(weight.is_leaf)  # True
print(weight.grad)  # You have two values: one for each parameter. You can make gradient descent!
# Leaf that doesn't requires grad (raw data):
print(x.is_leaf)  # True
print(x.grad)  # None (no warning/error because it is a leaf but no value because it doesn't require gradient)
```

Finally, the default behavior is exactly what you want in most cases for training a neural network: only the parameters keep their gradients after a back propagation and the minimum number of gradients needed for chain rules are actually computed by pytorch!

To put it in a nutshell: **you don't need to change anything from the default behavior if you want to optimize all the parameters of your neural network and only them.**